# F# |> (Pipeforward) 'block following let is unfinished' error

Tags: f#, excel-dna

Would someone please help me understand why the code below gives me the error 'Block following let is unfinished.  Expected an Expression'?  The value of x is expected to be a string list and that is how F# sees it.  So why does x not become a string list for use later in the function?

```
let fxProper (str : string) (values : obj[,]) =
    let x = 
        values
        |> Seq.cast<obj> 
        |> Seq.filter (fun x -> not (x :? ExcelEmpty)) 
        |> Seq.map string 
        |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: A function can not end with a `let` binding. You have to return a value from your function.

Comment: (This may be obvious but as you've yet to engage with your respondents I'll throw it in...) `x` is local to `fxProper`. So if you mean something more global than `fxProper` by 'later in the function', it would need to be moved out of the scope it's in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something with the x value you just set

```
let fxProper (str : string) (values : obj[,]) =
    let x = 
        values
        |> Seq.cast<obj> 
        |> Seq.filter (fun x -> not (x :? ExcelEmpty)) 
        |> Seq.map string 
        |> Seq.toList
    x
```

should work.

This

```
  let fxProper (str : string) (values : obj[,]) =
            values
            |> Seq.cast<obj> 
            |> Seq.filter (fun x -> not (x :? ExcelEmpty)) 
            |> Seq.map string 
            |> Seq.toList
```

should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right.  The let binding for `x` is working properly.  The error is telling you that your function `fxProper` isn't currently returning anything.  If your intent is to return x then you need to add it at the end of `fxProper` like below, otherwise just add a dummy return value until you're finished writing your function.

```
let fxProper (str : string) (values : obj[,]) =
    let x = 
        values
        |> Seq.cast<obj> 
        |> Seq.filter (fun x -> not (x :? ExcelEmpty)) 
        |> Seq.map string 
        |> Seq.toList
    x //this returns the value of x from fxProper, this could also just the default value of whatever you actually want to return here
```